# A strange result of simple purchase and total price code

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a simple code for purchase and total amount needed to be paid. Here's the code:

```
book_price = 5000
draw_price = 10000

book_qty = input("Amount of book you would like to buy: ")
draw_book_qty = input("Amount of drawing book you would like to buy: ")

book_total_price = book_price * book_qty
draw_book_total_price = draw_price * draw_book_qty

total_price = book_total_price + draw_book_total_price

print(f"Your total is: {total_price}")
```

However, the result that I get is not the amount that I want. Here's the result that I got:

```
Your total is: 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222111111111
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: bench test your algorithm with some numbers, use the same numbers to run it, compare.  If different, post the numbers (input values) here as well as the code

Comment: @Programnik The issue has nothing to do with numbers; `book_qty` is a string.

Comment: that may be your issue right there.  Is it concatenating strings instead of treating the inputs as numeric?

Comment: My post has been associated with a similar post and solved it immediately!

Turns out I needed to add int(input("")) to my book_qty and draw_book_qty